# How to compile blender add-on?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I compiled Blender as python module successfully in Windows Platform.
I can now `import bpy` without problems from my script.
Now I would like use an add-on from my script but I receive this error:

> AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.importgis.georaster" error, could not be found.

Obviously, because I haven't compiled this add-on. How do I compile it?

I solved this by enabling addon:
    bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable(module="BlenderGIS-master")

Comment: How did you compile Blender's bpy in the first place?

Comment: I compiled it with CMake in Windows 10 following this example: http://cobertos.com/compiling-blender-as-a-python-module-for-windows-10-x64/

Comment: It's not that the addon isn't compiled, it isn't enabled. Can enable addon in script using  `from addon_utils import enable` and `enable("BlenderGIS")` .. could be a bit dodgy with this addon by the looks.  Also checkout the code, may find a direct method via reading code, and using `from BlenderGIS import ...`  making it possible to bypass using operator altogether. (eg see if operator just sets parameters and calls a function, and use that funciton)

Comment: I solved this by enabling addon: bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable(module="BlenderGIS-master")

Comment: Nice, wasn't sure if window manager ops would work for bpy as py module.

Answer (score 3):

About the title of the question: you cannot compile add-ons because they are written in Python*.

Your script causes this error because it wasn't registered with Blender. Use the normal way (i.e. the regular Blender UI) to enable your add-on, and be sure to save your preferences so that it stays enabled. Once that's done it should simply work, also with Blender compiled as a module.

(*) Little footnote: Python is compiled into bytecode, but by the Python runtime itself, and doesn't require any action from the user contrary to "compiled languages" like Go or C.

Comment: I would avoid the normal blender installation, because I only need the module for my custom script. 
Anyway I will try as your suggestion and I will let you know. Thank you so much

Comment: You don't need a normal Blender installation, you just need to have your addon activated. The easiest way to do that in general is with the regular Blender UI, but @batFINGER also described another approach.